# Getting error while uploading the file using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, file-upload

[This is the error when i click on OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h67yM.png)I am trying to automate process with selenium in python so one of the step is to upl[image: Uploaded file can be seen here]oad file below is the input element before selenium tried to upload the file:

```
<input ct="FU" lsdata="{1:'Content',7:'ONSUBMIT',8:true}" lsevents="{Change:[{ResponseData:'delta',EnqueueCardinality:'single'},{}]}" id="WD039B" name="WD039B" type="file" tabindex="0" ti="0" class="lsFileupload__input urBorderBox urUpld" size="0" title="Content">
```

When selenium upload the file and click on "OK" i am getting error like file has not been chosen but i can see the file name against "Choose File" below is the same input element when selenium tried to click on "OK" after uploading:

```
<input ct="FU" lsdata="{0:'ERROR',1:'Content',7:'ONSUBMIT',8:true}" lsevents="{Change:[{ResponseData:'delta',EnqueueCardinality:'single'},{}]}" id="WD030D" name="WD030D" type="file" tabindex="0" ti="0" class="lsFileupload__input urBorderBox urUpldInv" size="0" title="Content">
```

When i manually tried to upload file after uploading same element looks like this:

```
<input ct="FU" lsdata="{1:'Content',7:'ONSUBMIT',8:true}" lsevents="{Change:[{ResponseData:'delta',EnqueueCardinality:'single'},{}]}" id="WD0302" name="WD0302" type="file" tabindex="0" ti="0" class="lsFileupload__input urBorderBox urUpld" size="0" title="Content" style="background-image: none;">
```

I am using following selenium code to upload the file:

```
upload_element=WebDriverWait(driver,v[3]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/form/input")))
time.sleep(5)

#driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('style')", upload_element)
time.sleep(5)

#To upload the file
upload_element.send_keys("C:\\Users\\e0481737\\.PyCharmCE2018.2\\config\\scratches\\Help File.pdf")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display = 'background-image: none;'; return arguments[0];", upload_element)
# until this point I am successful but when I click on "OK" it says that file is not chosen
time.sleep(5)

# to click on "OK" button
element = WebDriverWait(driver, wait_time).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div")))
time.sleep(5)
element.click()
```

Comment: Could you share the page you are trying to use?

Comment: @shubham How does `arguments[0].style.display = 'background-image: none;';`makes a difference to your usecase? Why would you `return arguments[0];`?

Comment: @DebanjanB  I was just trying one suggested method but that line is not useful, i removed it

Comment: @j.barrio actually this page is company's internal page so can't share more details about it

Comment: @shubham Questions seeking debugging help ("**Why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)